# How do devices like an Amazon Echo connect to networks

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, wifi, raspberry-pi3

For example with an amazon echo, to connect it to a network, you load up the app on your phone and the echo is visible to your phone. Is this done through bluetooth or is the echo broadcasting a wireless network that the phone sees?

I am trying to make a device (based on a raspberry pi) that needs to be connected to a wireless but it is not connected to a mouse, keyboard, or monitor and I don't want to have to SSH into the pi to put in the network credentials. I am hoping to somehow connect a phone to it on first bootup and put in the network credentials so it can connect and do the rest of its job. Any advice or information would be helpful. I hope I have described what I am looking for correctly. Thank you.